# How to check which line of VBA code is causing errors

Tags: excel, vba, macos, debugging

I am trying to debug a long code I wrote and I need to step line by line.

The thing is I am on a mac and don't know how to use an F8 in that case. Could anyone tell me how can I do that otherwise and how do I know which line is causing problems with execution?

Comment: See this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/using-office-for-mac-2011-is-there-a-macro-step/604a4eb6-473d-4fff-96a2-434e6c9b4ffe

Answer (score 11):

To check which line is giving you the error, you can use the `ERL` property. See this sample code below.

```
Sub sample()
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo Whoa

10    Debug.Print "A"
20    Debug.Print "B"
30    i = "Sid"
40    Debug.Print "A"

50    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox "Error on Line : " & Erl
End Sub
```

For this to work, you will have to number the code lines as I have done above. Run the above code and see what happens.

Answer (score 11):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim lNum As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    lNum = 1 / 0

ErrExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume

End Sub
```

When you get to Stop, then Step Into twice. If you don't have F8, you should have a menu item for stepping into a line. Resume will take you back to the line that caused the error.

Comment: Actually, **Resume** will take you to the line **after** the error.

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click the toolbar.
2. Choose "Customize..."
3. Select "Debug"
4. Drag "Step Into" into your toolbar.