# How to reset calculation mode in VBA after error

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

**Question:**

In VBA, is there any way to execute some clean up code after an error is raised without either A) losing the detail of the native error messages by manually raising the error, or B) inserting & maintaining line numbers throughout my code? ***Edit for clarification:*** The detail being lost is the 'debug' button on the native error message which then highlights the line causing the error.

**More Background/Info:**

I want to change the calculation mode to manual at the start, but I want to ensure it's changed back before the code exits. This is fine if there's no error, but the only way I can think to ensure it's raised even if an error is encountered is to change the exception handler to something like `On Error Resume Next`, ensure the calculation mode is restored, then manually raise the error. But doing this loses details like where the error occurred; making it more difficult to resolve issues.

The only 'solution' I've been able to find is to manually (or using a tool) add line numbers which can then be used in the manually raised error; but this seems a pain to maintain and (imo) makes the code a bit messy.

If these truly are the only two options (and my fruitless searching seems to suggest that's the case; but sorry if this has been answered somewhere and I just failed to find it) then so be it; I'll have to opt for one of them. But I just wanted to see if anyone knows of another option?

**Dummy Code:**

(Just a quick mock-up of what it might look like with the 'raise the error manually and lose the details' method). ***Edit for clarification:*** The error in the below code is simple just to have *something* throwing an error; here it would be obvious where the error was, but in the 'real' problem it might not be obvious where the error was triggered (which is where the debug option on the native error message comes in handy).

```
Sub Example()

    Dim OrigCalcMode as XlCalculation
    OrigCalcMode = Application.Calculation

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Main code would go here, but to simply induce an error...
    Dim Val as Integer
    Val = 1 / 0

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        MsgBox ("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Error Description: " & Err.Description)
        Err.Clear

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.Calculation = OrigCalcMode

End Sub
```

Comment: what details are you losing?  I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish as your Mock doesn't lose any error details

Comment: Instead of `On Error GoTo 0` you can state a place in the code where it should pick up the macro when an error is detected. e.g. `On Error GoTo ExitSub` where `ExitSub:` is then added near the end of the macro and code can be added afterwards. https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/error-handling/

Comment: You can then also use Debug.Print to capture any error messages you may want to be able to view, which get added to the `immediate` window in the VB editor

Comment: *But doing this loses details like where the error occurred; making it more difficult to resolve issues.* That is what the `err.source` field is for - you are supposed to fill it with interesting information when doing an `err.raise`. That also applies to the other fields. Often you merely propagate the original error but you don't have to.

Comment: @Sorceri sorry, that was my fault; I didn't make the question clear enough. I've edited for clarity but essentially the 'detail' being lost is the line where the error occurred (which is normally provided via the debug button, so my choice of the word 'detail' was poor).

Comment: @Tragamor, that doesn't quite get what I need (which was the line where the error had occurred; but that's my fault for not proving clearer details. However, your answer caused me to google around about with the debug.print aspect, which led me to another question which I feel effectively answers my question (particularly when coupled with Tim's answer below). So I've marked this question as a duplicate, and thank you :)

Comment: @Lundt, sorry my question wasn't clear enough so I don't think err.source would work (unless I'm mistaken). The 'detail' (poor choice of words on my part) being lost was the line the error had occurred on. Either way I've marked the question as a duplicate after another comment helped me find something that largely resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is maybe a little too simple - typically there's the consideration of (eg) how to handle errors in calling code, and how to decide if an error is "fatal" (all subsequent steps should be aborted) or recoverable.

A typical approach might be something like:

```vb
Sub Example()

    Dim OrigCalcMode As XlCalculation
    
    OrigCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    On Error GoTo haveError

    ' Main code would go here, but to simply induce an error...
    Dim Val As Integer
    Val = 1 / 0

cleanExit:
    Application.Calculation = OrigCalcMode     'make sure to reset this
    Exit Sub 'don't run into the error handler
    
haveError:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Error Description: " & Err.Description
    '<Make any decisions about what to do with this specific error>
    Resume cleanExit 'Resume clears the Err object
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that's a clean way of handling errors, however on it's own it doesn't quite do what I was looking for; but that's my fault as I don't think my original question was clear enough. In trying to find additional details based on other comments on this question I found [question #16398261](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398261/how-to-check-which-line-of-vba-code-is-causing-errors) where someone proposed using stop and resume. I think coupling that with your answer and a debug variable to toggle simply handling the issue vs highlighting it is the way forward. Thanks for your answer :)